# XPages, opening a dialog from another dialog's on hide event. Not working

Tags: xpages

I have set for the onhide event of a dialog the following:

```
<xe:dialog id="dlgSelectYourItems">
    <xe:this.onHide><![CDATA[
        console.log('onHide dialog dlgSelectYourItems');
        console.log('calling dialog dlgCard');
        XSP.openDialog('#{id:dlgCard}');
]]></xe:this.onHide>
</xe:dialog>
```

In the browser console I see:

```
onHide dialog dlgSelectYourItems
calling dialog dlgCard
```

But no dialog is appearing.

If I check the source of my xpage:

```
<span id="view:_id1:_id237:cbMain:includeContent:_id4700:_id4823:_id4974:_id5039:dlgSelectYourItems" style="display: none" onHide="console.log('onHide dialog dlgSelectYourItems');
console.log('calling dialog dlgCard');
XSP.openDialog('view:_id1:_id237:cbMain:includeContent:_id4700:_id4823:_id4974:_id5039:dlgCard');" title="Select items"></span>
```

and

```
<div class="modal xsp-responsive-modal " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="view:_id1:_id237:cbMain:includeContent:_id4700:_id4823:_id4974:_id5039:dlgCard_title" id="view:_id1:_id237:cbMain:includeContent:_id4700:_id4823:_id4974:_id5039:dlgCard" widgetid="view:_id1:_id237:cbMain:includeContent:_id4700:_id4823:_id4974:_id5039:dlgCard" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 920px; top: 633px;"> 
</div>
```

so it looks dialog dlgCard is available but it wont open.

What can be the cause?

//desperate Malin

Comment: Could you provide the source of a minimal reproducer? Kind of hard to assess from the code snippet

Comment: In your browser, open the developer panel and set a breakpoint in the line console.log('calling dialog dlgCard'); Then dive into the XSP call and see what it tries to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to check is that your second dialog actually works (use a button to test).

It probably does (but you should make sure) - and I guess that you might have been caught in the mysterious ways of events in XPages... There can be many reasons for issues but I find doing something like what you are trying sometimes just don't work because of the ways things work "underneath". I'm not the right person to try and explain that...

However, one thing I would try would be to "separate" the work. So you could try to put the code to open the second dialog on the e.g. button that closes the first dialog and put it in an `oncomplete` event (which really is outside of the dialog that you close). You could use a viewScope variable to carry over any "state" that you need to control if/how to open the second dialog.

If that is too much of a rewrite for your code then you could also try to add the `XSP.openDialog(...)` in a small `setTimeout` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) just to decouple it from the events of closing the first dialog...

/John

Comment: Thank you John ! The setTimeOut solved the problem!

Comment: Super! Glad you got it working 